# Клиент не получает ответ от сервера Fetch Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, multer

Отправляю данные на Сервер с помощью Fetch Js, но почему-то ответ от сервера не получаю.

Post запрос, отправляю данные товара (Название, описание, фотографии и т.д). Сервер принимает запрос и с помощью multer обрабатывает его (загрузка фото и тд). Смотрел логи, данные на сервер приходят, он обрабатывает и отправляет ответ, но клиенту он не доходит (Постоянное "ожидание"), такое бывает только, если сервер отправляет текст с ошибкой, иначе все нормально. Но если отправить запрос без фотографий, то сервер просто отправляет "OK"(Как и должен). Так же если я отключу сервер, то браузер сразу же скинет запрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Клиент:

```js
        const formData = new FormData();
        const fileField = new Blob(document.getElementById('File').files, {type: "image/png"});

        formData.append('title', document.getElementById('title').value);
        formData.append('disc', document.getElementById('disc').value);
        formData.append('price', document.getElementById('price').value);
        formData.append('viberT', document.getElementById('viberT').value);
        formData.append('vkS', document.getElementById('vkS').value);
        formData.append('wappT', document.getElementById('wappT').value);
        formData.append('teleN', document.getElementById('teleN').value);
        formData.append('gallery', fileField);

        try {
            const response = await fetch(`Тут нужный URL`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        });
            const result = await response;
            console.log(result)
            console.log(result.message);
            console.log(result.text);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
```

Сервер:

```js
app.post('*', urlencodedParser, async  function (req, res, next) {
    let url = req._parsedUrl.pathname;
    let textR = "OK";
    console.log("Пришел запрос");
    if (url === '/cool-profile') {
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            if (err !== undefined){
                textR = `Произошла ошибка! Проверьте введенные данные\nОтвет сервера: ${err.message}`;
                res.send(textR);
            } else {
                res.send(textR);
            }
            console.log("Отправил ответ: " + textR);
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: fileField.files[0] - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Пробовал ставить и то, что в документации и "document.getElementById('File').files[0]", не помогло совсем